# Calling mysql procedure using drop down list in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have my drop down form like this:

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" >
    <p>Get a Report of each Gene:<br>
        <select  name="Prot_Id">
            <!--option value="" selected disabled>Select a rating</option--> 
            <option value="" selected disabled></option>
            <option value="chr">chr12:111,843,752-111,889,427</option>
            <option value="chr">chr19:17,186,591-17,324,104</option>
            <option value="chr">chr2:102,927,962-103,015,21</option>
            <option value="chr">chr2:204,732,511-204,738,683</option>
            <option value="chr">chr4:123,372,626-123,377,650</option>
            <option value="chr">chr4:123,533,783-123,542,212</option>
            <option value="chr">chr6:159,456,027-159,466,184</option>
        </select>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Go" />
</form>
```

I have one MySQL stored procedure `Chrome_Seq` with one input parameter (eg:chr2:102,927,962-103,015,21 it's the display name for the drop down box).. Now I am writing a PHP page to call this procedure and show the result as table. Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['chr'])) {

    echo "hi 11";
    $id=$_POST['chr'];

    echo "<table>";
    //connect to database
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "KCC_Celiac_Disease");

    //run the store proc
    echo "hello";

    $query= "call Chromo_Seq(".'"'.$id.'")';

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error());


    //loop the result set

    echo "<tbody>";
    // point to the beginning of the array
    $check = mysqli_data_seek($result, 0); 
    $rownew = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    foreach($rownew as $k => $v ) {
        echo "<th>".$k."</th>";
    }

    $check = mysqli_data_seek($result, 0); 

    while ($rownew = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($rownew as $k => $v) {
            echo "<td>".$v."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>"."<br>";
    } 
    echo "</tbody></table>";
}
?>
```

Whenever I select a value from dropdown it should run the procedure with that parameter and return the value but I am not getting any result in my output. It's blank.

Comment: I am not sure if this part is correct: `$query= "call Chromo_Seq(".'"'.$id.'")';` why are you appending a period to the sequence function call here ?

Comment: i think its not entering in the first if statement because its not printing the echo "hi 11"

Comment: you are passing every time chr as value. I think value should be "chr19:17,186,591-17,324,104" some thing like this

Comment: but whatever I select in the drop box it should pick that value... thats why i have given same value "chr" for all...

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['chr'])) {` should be `if (isset($_POST['Prot_Id'])) {` Try that and see if that works.

Comment: You also need to change the value parameter for the elements of your drop down list otherwise you will always get the same value: `chr`

Comment: Also change `$id=$_POST['chr'];` to `$id=$_POST['Prot_Id'];`